# Attribute extraction from Metadata using Python3

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, nltk, text-extraction

Here is the input:

> Magic Bullet Magic Bullet MBR-1701 17-Piece Express Mixing Set 4.1 out of 5 stars 3,670 customer reviews | 300 answered questions List Price: $59.99 Price: $47.02 & FREE Shipping You Save: $12.97 (22%) Only 5 left in stock - order soon. Ships from and sold by shopincaldwell. This fits your . Enter your model number to make sure this fits. 17-piece high-speed mixing system chops, whips, blends, and more Includes power base, 2 blades, 2 cups, 4 mugs, 4 colored comfort lip rings, 2 sealed lids, 2 vented lids, and recipe book Durable see-through construction; press down for results in 10 seconds or less Microwave- and freezer-safe cups and mugs; dishwasher-safe parts Product Built to North American Electrical Standards 23 new from $43.95 4 used from $35.00 There is a newer model of this item: Magic Bullet Blender, Small, Silver, 11 Piece Set $34.00 (2,645) In Stock.

Expected Output:

```
Title: "Magic Bullet MBR-1701 17-Piece Express Mixing Set", 
Customer Rating : "4.1", 
customer reviews : "3670", 
List Price : $59.99, 
Offer Price : $47.02, 
Shipping : FREE Shipping
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. On this site, you need to make more of an effort to formulate your question more concretely (preferably in a way that is potentially useful to others as well), and to include your own code as a starting point so people can identify what you need to know. See the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for information on how to write a great question.

Comment: Also that's unstructured data, not metadata.

Comment: Sounds like a sequence labelling / NER problem. What have you tried?